# When can AはBです mean 'A has B'

Tags: grammar, copula

> 国土交通省は、港がある県や市などと一緒にクルーズ船のための岸壁をつくる計画です
>   The ministry, together with cities and prefectures that have ports, has a plan to build wharfs for cruise ships.

If I strip the example sentence to the important parts I have

> 国土交通省は計画です
>   The ministry **is** a plan

I keep seeing sentences of the form AはBです which seem to mean 'A **has** B' rather than 'A **is** B'.

When and why is this possible? Is it incorrect to say:

> 国土交通省は計画があります

What is the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can say/write (a bit less colloquially):

> ～～はXXする計画です。
>   ～～はXXする予定です。
>   ～～はXXする考えです。

to mean

> ～～はXXすることを計画しています。 ~~ is planning to do XX　
>   ～～はXXすることを予定しています。 ~~ is planning/scheduled to do XX
>   ～～はXXしようと考えています。/ するつもりです。 ~~ is thinking of doing XX / intend to do XX

respectively.

Answer (score 3):

> 国土交通省はつくる計画です。

This should be the correct stripping.
"There is a plan in which the ministry will build blahblah."

> *国土交通省は計画です。

This does not make sense.

> 国土交通省は計画があります。

This a correct sentence.